# MySQL: Como localizar string a partir de determinado caractere?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou desenvolvendo um pequeno sistema - e nao sou um expert em MySQL (entao a duvida talvez seja boba)

Recebo do cliente uma string gigante com 580 caracteres - essa string contem uma serie de informacoes, como nome, data de nascimento, endereco... etc..

Armazeno a string no mySQL.

Porem, para localizar cada registro eu preciso saber o CPF da pessoa.

O CPF esta localizado a partir do caractere numero 12 ate o 22 - ou seja - algo assim:

1234567890A**27485962812**CLOVIS DA SILVA

onde o CPF = 27485962812

Como localizar TODOS os registros do banco que equivalem a esse CPF?

Pensei em usar "LIKE" mas tenho medo que - sabe-se la - uma mesma sequencia seja igual em outra parte da string dando um resultado falso.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE CAMPO1 LIKE '%CPF%'
```

Primeiramente pensei em desmembrar todos os dados e colocar cada info numa coluna propria do banco de dados, mas fiquei preocupado em "desmembrar" algo errado - e nao sei se fazendo assim seria a pratica mais recomendada - talvez deixando todas as infos numa coluna unica como estou recebendo seja mais rapido para processar depois.

outra coisa - usando esse mesmo raciocinio - é possivel filtrar os registros por uma data? Isso pq no meio da string tambem tenho a "data de validade" da informacao.

assim eu so exibiria no final, os registros ainda "validos" (isso é o de menos pq uma vez tendo todos os registros do CPF eu sei como fazer um looping e eliminar os registros "invalidos" - mas acho que seria legal e mais elegante - se a propria query ja trouxesse a informacao certa)

No caso a DATA DE VALIDADE estaria localizada entre o caractere 300 e 309 (DD/MM/YYYY) = 10 caracteres.

alguma ideia?

muito obrigado pelo tempo dedicado em me ajudar :D

Daniel

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Comment: Eu acredito que seja melhor tratar esses dados antes de inserir na base, será muito mais facil de realizar a busca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar oa função SUBSTRING:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE SUBSTRING(CAMPO1 ,12,11) = 'cpf';
```

Explicando a função -> `SUBSTRING(Coluna, a partir deste carcter, quantidade de caracteres).`

Em relação a data, a mesma lógica se aplica, coloca um AND substring localização da data na string e faz a lógica com o valor.